# how to monitor Virtual IPs in Zabbix?

Tags: cloud, monitoring, monitor, zabbix, virtual-ip-address

I have a Virtual IP which is linked to two other private IP . I wanna monitor to my virtual IP with Zabbix . those private IP have few service like nginx that i wanna to monitor with zabbix. if any one have any idea .ping me . i will be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor virtual IP in the same way you can monitor any other IP in Zabbix - just create a host for it and link the appropriate templates.

Based on further information supplied, the problem is that the service only listens on the localhost IP, 127.0.0.1. You can:

- change the key and specify the localhost IP: `net.tcp.port[127.0.0.1,44334]`
- change your service to listen on all IP addresses, or at least the ones you expect it to be available on

Comment: that's not a helpful information at all. what do you consider to be "wrong output" ?

Comment: on my private ip`s ....i have web app . when i use private ip in zabbix then it app is running but when i put VIP then it shows app is not running.

Comment: what do you mean by "it shows" ? what is the item type and key ? what values does the item receive in each case ?

Comment: type-Zabbix agent........key-net.tcp.port[,44334]........type of info--Numeric (unsigned).......data_type--Decimal................when i use private ip value return in zabbix dashboard is 1.....but when i use VIP then value is 0....i dunno why this is happenning...

Comment: are you sure your service listens on that port on all interfaces ?

Comment: what's your VIP ? run on the system : "netstat -ntl | grep 44334" - what's the output ?

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:44334         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN ..................................port is open .

Comment: and there's your reason - your service listens on the localhost ip, 127.0.0.1, only. will update the answer accordingly.