# How to monitor virtual IP with zabbix?

Tags: centos, monitoring, virtualhost, zabbix, virtual-ip-address

in some cluster environments, there are pair servers that are HA 2 by 2. for example i have server1 with IP 22.1.1.1 and server2 with IP 22.1.1.2.
server1 is giving service and server2 is standby. there is this virtual IP 22.1.1.3 that other servers connect to it to get services from server1 and server2.

now i need to monitor this virtual IP to see if it is up and other servers outside its VLAN can connect to it. how i can do this in zabbix?

i don't have an actual physical server to create in zabbix according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055899/how-to-monitor-virtual-ips-in-zabbix) question. i tried to create one but i got errors. also this question is asked 3 years ago. is there any new features i can use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a host with agent ip 22.1.1.3 and monitor it in agentless mode.

You can ping it (`icmpping`), connect to a tcp port that you know it's open (`net.tcp.service`) or, in case of a web service,  do a http call with the http agent and react accordingly.

Just create the correct items/templates according to the [simple check](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/simple_checks) and [http agent](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/http) documentation.

Comment: what should i set for username and password? i dont have a machine to create a user

Comment: Excuse me, I don't understand. What are you referring to?

Comment: for agantless monitoring. its items requires username and password.

Comment: You did not read the documentation. There's a note at the beginning that says clearly: "User name and Password fields in simple check item configuration are used for VMware monitoring items; ignored otherwise."

Comment: i read the documents but i did get errors due to username and password in the past. i was making sure before i start testing. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You [do not need a physical server](http://www.zabbixbook.com/2016/11/22/can-i-have-a-host-without-interfaces/) to create a host.

You can create a host with the target IP address and use various items against it - based on your question, you do not need agent items, but some other (remote) type.